# How to demonstrate a third quantitative attribute in a scatter plot effectively

Tags: data-visualization, scatterplot

I am trying to create a scatter plot that illustrates the relationship between x and y with a third quantitative attribute, z.  However, I have a couple of constraints:

1. I do not want to use gradient of colors to demonstrate z since the journals I plan on sending my paper to will charge me a hefty amount for including figures with colors, and
2. I have roughly about 800 data points in my scatter plot.  I tried creating a bubble chart in R using different sizes of the bubbles for z, but because there are a lot of overlapping black bubbles, I am afraid that this will not be an effective figure.

If you know of any alternatives,  I would love to hear about them.

Comment: 3-D scatterplot would preserve granularity.

Comment: Is using a gradient but with gray also a constraint? Like so http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/scale_grey.html